# Why is uniform convergence not necessary in Lebesgue convergence theorems?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, uniform-convergence

In baby Rudin you can find proofs for interchanging limits and Riemann integration. i.e. Swapping the order of them. However Rudin requires that the functions uniformly converge to show these are true.

In measure theory I came across the dominated Lebesgue convergence, and monotone Lebesgue convergence theorems. These can be used to also give a proof for interchanging limits and integration. However the assumptions on the sequences of functions are different. Why is uniform convergence not necessary for the proof of interchanging limits and integration in Lebesgue integration / measure theory, but it is necessary when dealing with Riemann integrals?

I'm guessing that it has something to do with Egorovs theorem. But I havent connected all the dots myself.

Comment: In the theory of Riemann integrals you make strong hypthesis to give easy proofs  of weaker theorems. In Lebesgue's Theory you try to prove theorems under minimal hypothesis. Uniform convergnce is too strong an assumption in many situations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Lebesgue's integral extend Riemann's, every convergence theorem for Lebesgue integral also holds for Riemann integral as long as the sequence of functions involved, and its limit, are Riemann integrable functions.

However, the pointwise limit of Riemann integrable functions might not be Riemann integrable, so stating such results in the context of Riemann integral would look a bit awkward.

Moreover, as I believe underlies  @Kavi's comment, Riemann integration is better suited to introducing students to the theory of integration at an early stage, when they might not yet be prepared to work with so many different notions of convergence, so I think it is pedagogically correct to stick with the simplest convergence Theorem, namely the one about uniform convergence.